# NSAttributedString to and from encoded HTML

Tags: html, ios, encoding, ckeditor, nsattributedstring

For one of our cross platform software solution (iOS app + website), we need to allow **display and edit** rich text in the app. Our solution only supports only few character attributes - bold, italic, underline, basic text color and hyperlinks (link only on website, not app).

The rich text is stored and transmitted as encoded HTML text by existing website. My question is related to iOS app where we need to support this.

So far I had success converting *encoded HTML* text to *NSAttributedString* using this (Screenshot from my sample app attached)-

```
NSString *richTextHTML = self.textViewTop.text;
richTextHTML = [richTextHTML stringByDecodingHTMLEntities]; // Decodes HTML entities like &lt;p&gt; to <p> etc.

NSAttributedString *attribString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[richTextHTML dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                    options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType}
                                                         documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

self.textViewBottom.attributedText = attribString;
```

Here `stringByDecodingHTMLEntities` is a category method that decodes HTML Entities. Example of encoded HTML text is -

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;bold&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;em&gt;italic&lt;/em&gt;&lt;u&gt;underline&lt;/u&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color:rgb(255, 0, 0)&quot;&gt;color&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

[image]
However, after editing the NSAttributedString, I don't have existing method to convert back into encoded HTML. And, that's the problem.

I tried this but it only gives back HTML document-

```
- (NSString *)htmlStringFromAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)attribText {
    NSDictionary *exportParams = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType};
    NSData *htmlData = [attribText dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, attribText.length) documentAttributes:exportParams error:nil];
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

[image]
Can you please provide some easy way or you think I need to enumerate over text runs of NSAttributedString and created encoded HTML string myself?

As a side note / key points -

1. App supports iOS 7 and above.
2. At website, we are using third party library CKEditor to do the same.